# How to record a screen video

Tags: video

When I want to analyze a piece of music or watch a video lesson — I need to be online.
What alternatives do I have out there?

In corona-times it might be a quite useful and frequent problem:
*How to copy a video (of a teacher)*, or *How to recorded and saved a video on your device.*

---

**Edit:**
As this question is asked to be representative for anybody — answers for any system are welcome.

Comment: I find [youtube-dl](http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/) to be quite handy for this kind of thing. It doesn't do an actual screen recording but it lets you download the video from YouTube and a lot of other streaming video sites. It's a command line program so if you aren't used to that kind of thing there might be a learning curve. But I think it's worth it because it works for so many sites.

Comment: If "real" methods fail, you can even record the screen with a video camera. ;) Or if your device has a video output, you can record it with a suitable video recorder. Or a "game capture" device.

Comment: You’re going to need to go online to retrieve the source in the first place, unless you get someone to do it for you, so you may as well just stay online :-)

Answer (score 2):

You don't say what operating system you're running.  If you have a modern one, you may have the software you need already installed.  Have a look at [How to Record the Screen on Your Windows PC or Mac](https://uk.pcmag.com/how-to/127249/how-to-record-the-screen-on-your-windows-pc-or-mac)

Comment: I‘m asking for everyone and so as win10, iPad, Galaxy.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't much detail here about your operating system, your browser, what service the video is hosted on, etc.

For starters, try seeing if you can download the video. If it's an educational website/service, there's a good chance you'll find success just locating a download/save button.

As @user66401 suggested in a comment, you can use [YoutubeDL](http://ytdl-org.github.io/youtube-dl/) to download from youtube and a few other services; if it's on youtube, I would also recommend taking a look at [YtMP3](https://ytmp3.cc/en13/) which is a lot easier if you don't have experience operating from the command line (which is where YoutubeDL runs).

You could also try using built-in screen recorders; on Windows 10 at least, you can use Win+Alt+R to start screen recording and just play the video, and when you're done press the same combination or click the stop button on the control bar. If that gives you an error, try opening the Game Bar with Win+G and manually starting a capture. It's designed for games but it's just a simple screen recorder so there's no reason you can't use it for anything.